# Tag Badge Clarification

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

According to SO , one deserves a tag badge , must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

when checking my jquery answers , i found so:

[My jQuery Tag Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3025259%20%5Bjquery%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20score%3A1)

I feel confused here .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're asking why you don't have a Bronze jquery tag badge, it's because your score is still at 75.

[image]

The number on the left (75) is the score in non-wiki answers. The number on the right (148) is the total number of posts you have in this tag.

So, you've given enough answers, but your score in answers is not yet high enough.

Hover over the gray box with the number on the left (the box containing the number 75, in this case) to see how the numbers are composed.

Comment: i never noticed so , thanks for the info.

Comment: No, the number on the right is the *total post count*, not the total score. You need to look at the tooltip for the *75* number to see how many of those are non-CW answers.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks @MartijnPieters for fixing it. And ProllyGeek: you're welcome.